# A strategy to migrate Android clients to socket.io 2.0

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

The new 2.0 socket.io server is not compatible with the previous versions. For web clients the migration can be painful (see [Suggested way to deploy major socket.io upgrade (1.4.5 to 2.0) to a production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44676717/5695504)) but is manageable.
For Android clients however, I don't see how to manage the transition period without some way to allow both 1.x and 2.x clients to work.

My idea was to run two servers (1.x and 2.0) and use a bridge on the server side that connects to the two servers and relays the messages to the clients. For that the bridge needs to connect to two different socket.io versions, is that even possible ?
Does someone else have the same problem, and then thought of a better strategy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the V2.0.x clients (both JS and Android) are able to connect to a 1.7.3 server and receive messages. I've not tested emitting since in my setup the clients are only receiving messages, the emitting is done server-side by a process distinct from the socket.io server.

So in that case the migration strategy could simply be to upgrade the clients first, and the server later when all/most client are updated. It's also possible to run two versions of socket.io server (and sending messages to both), to serve non-upgraded clients until you decide to pull the plug on them.